# Shell Scripting: "grep -w" not to select words separated by "-"

Tags: shell, unix

I have 3 words.

```
abcd-1234
abcd-abcd
abcd
```

Is it possible to select/print the 3rd word "abcd" with grep -w or a similar command?

Comment: May be I didn't explain it correctly. I only need one "abcd"

Comment: Don't make us guess:  For the given input in your question, please show precisely what output you want.

Comment: What do you mean by "select"? You want to `echo abcd`? Does "select" mean print the lines containing the string `abcd` that are not followed by a dash? Why not just `grep abcd | grep -v abcd-`?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
grep '[a-zA-Z]'
```

more specific, alphabet from begining:

```
echo "abcd-1234" | grep -o '^[a-zA-Z]*'
```

it should be good for given examples,

try this, regarding from your comment

data.txt

> abcd-1234
>
> abcd-4678
>
> abcd
>
> abcd-as334s
>
> abcd-abcd

```
cat data.txt | grep -ow '^[a-zA-Z]*' | sort -u
```

Comment: The 2nd part can be numbers or letters. So words can be "abcd-1234" or "abcd-xfgh" or "abcd-a8n6"

Comment: Does it change anything? If the second part are numbers or letters, how does it matter?

Answer (score 1):

And why do you want to achieve this using `-w` if you can simply achieve this by `-v` (*A.K.A.* `--invert-match`):

```
grep -v "-" data.txt
```

Output:

```
abcd
```

Ok, `-w` only gets entire words, but a hyphen does not always split a word. If you don't like the hyphen, best thing to say is that you don't like the hyphen (hence `-v "-"`).